# How can I use StreamBuilder with Moor and bloc in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, bloc

I am studying the Moor database and I am trying to use StreamBuilder with bloc and repository. If I skip the repository and use the Dao in the bloc, I can use it in my StreamBuilder but I want to pass it through the repository to map the generated code from Moor to my domain model but I don't know how. How can I achieve this?

```
@UseDao(tables: [SalesmanTable])
class SalesmanDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase> with _$SalesmanDaoMixin{
  final AppDatabase db;

  SalesmanDao(this.db) : super(db);

  Future<List<SalesmanTableData>> getAllSalesman() =>
      select(salesmanTable).get();

  Stream<List<SalesmanTableData>> watchAllSalesman() =>
      select(salesmanTable).watch();

  Future insertSalesman(SalesmanTableData salesman) =>
      into(salesmanTable).insert(salesman);
}
```

```
class SalesmanRepositoryImpl extends SalesmanRepository{

  final SalesmanDao dao;

  SalesmanRepositoryImpl({required this.dao});

  @override
  Future<void> insertSalesman(Salesman salesman) async {
    final SalesmanTableData salesmanModel = salesman.toMap() as SalesmanTableData;
    await dao.insertSalesman(salesmanModel);
    return;
  }
```

```
class SalesmanBloc extends Bloc<SalesmanEventBloc, SalesmanStateBloc> {

  // final SalesmanDao dao;
  **using dao here works**
  final SalesmanRepository repository;

  SalesmanBloc(// this.dao
      this.repository) : super(InitialState());

  @override
  Stream<SalesmanStateBloc> mapEventToState(SalesmanEventBloc event) async* {
    if (event is InsertSalesmanEvent) {
      try {
        await repository.insertSalesman(event.salesman);
        yield InsertSuccessState(event.salesman);
      } catch (e) {
        ErrorState(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
class _StreamBState extends State<StreamB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = BlocProvider.of<SalesmanBloc>(context).dao; 
**if I use the dao here it works but I ended up using the generated code from Moor**
    return StreamBuilder<List<SalesmanTableData>>(
        stream: bloc,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<SalesmanTableData>> snapshot) {
          final salesmanList = snapshot.data ?? [];

          return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: salesmanList.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                final salesman = salesmanList[index];
                return Container(
                  height: 30,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(salesmanList[index].name),
                  ),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```